# Missplaced dropdown and not closing when clicking outside multiselect on select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

As you can see on this example below, when I center the elements of my page with a margin in auto, the dropdown is misaligned. Moreover, clicking outside the dropdown does not close it automatically, which should be the case (clicking on the sides and below the dropdown causes the problem).

There is my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.multiple-select').select2({
    closeOnSelect: false,
  })
})
```

```css
html,
body {
    margin: auto;
    background: #fafcff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #8a91b4;
    width: 60%;
}

/* Select2 CSS */
.select2-container {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1em
}

.select2-container[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-left: 20px
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    min-height: 32px;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__clear {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1em
}

.select2-container .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    resize: none;
    height: 18px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: keep-all
}

.select2-container .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none
}

.select2-dropdown {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -100000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1051
}

.select2-results {
    display: block
}

.select2-results__options {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

.select2-results__option {
    padding: 6px;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none
}

.select2-results__option--selectable {
    cursor: pointer
}

.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown {
    left: 0
}

.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--above {
    border-bottom: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0
}

.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown--below {
    border-top: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0
}

.select2-search--dropdown {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px
}

.select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
    padding: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none
}

.select2-search--dropdown.select2-search--hide {
    display: none
}

.select2-close-mask {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: #fff;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0)
}

.select2-hidden-accessible {
    border: 0 !important;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0) !important;
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%) !important;
    clip-path: inset(50%) !important;
    height: 1px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 1px !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
    color: #444;
    line-height: 28px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 26px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-right: 0px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__placeholder {
    color: #999
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
    height: 26px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    width: 20px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b {
    border-color: #888 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 4px 0 4px;
    height: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0
}

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
    float: left
}

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
    left: 1px;
    right: auto
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--single {
    background-color: #eee;
    cursor: default
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
    display: none
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b {
    border-color: transparent transparent #888 transparent;
    border-width: 0 4px 5px 4px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: text;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    position: relative
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple.select2-selection--clearable {
    padding-right: 25px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__clear {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    padding: 1px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    white-space: nowrap
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__display {
    cursor: default;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 5px
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    color: #999;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 4px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0
}

.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove:hover,
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove:focus {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    color: #333;
    outline: none
}

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: auto
}

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__display {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 2px
}

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove {
    border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-right: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px
}

.select2-container--default[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__clear {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: auto
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--focus .select2-selection--multiple {
    border: solid black 1px;
    outline: 0
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection--multiple {
    background-color: #eee;
    cursor: default
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--disabled .select2-selection__choice__remove {
    display: none
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--single,
.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--multiple {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0
}

.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--single,
.select2-container--default.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--multiple {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0
}

.select2-container--default .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
    border: 1px solid #aaa
}

.select2-container--default .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results>.select2-results__options {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
    padding-left: 1em
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__group {
    padding-left: 0
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
    margin-left: -1em;
    padding-left: 2em
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
    margin-left: -2em;
    padding-left: 3em
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
    margin-left: -3em;
    padding-left: 4em
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
    margin-left: -4em;
    padding-left: 5em
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option .select2-results__option {
    margin-left: -5em;
    padding-left: 6em
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--group {
    padding: 0
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--disabled {
    color: #999
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--selected {
    background-color: #ddd
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__option--highlighted.select2-results__option--selectable {
    background-color: #5897fb;
    color: white
}

.select2-container--default .select2-results__group {
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    padding: 6px
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 50%, #eee 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 50%, #eee 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 50%, #eee 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', GradientType=0)
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single:focus {
    border: 1px solid #5897fb
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
    color: #444;
    line-height: 28px
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 26px;
    margin-right: 20px
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__placeholder {
    color: #999
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
    background-color: #ddd;
    border: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    height: 26px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    width: 20px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #ccc 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #ccc 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee 50%, #ccc 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', endColorstr='#FFCCCCCC', GradientType=0)
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b {
    border-color: #888 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 4px 0 4px;
    height: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -4px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0
}

.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__clear {
    float: left
}

.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
    border: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    left: 1px;
    right: auto
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single {
    border: 1px solid #5897fb
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
    background: transparent;
    border: none
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow b {
    border-color: transparent transparent #888 transparent;
    border-width: 0 4px 5px 4px
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--single {
    border-top: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #eee 50%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #eee 50%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #eee 50%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', endColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', GradientType=0)
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--single {
    border-bottom: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #fff 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #eee 50%, #fff 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eee 50%, #fff 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFEEEEEE', endColorstr='#FFFFFFFF', GradientType=0)
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: text;
    outline: 0;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple:focus {
    border: 1px solid #5897fb
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__clear {
    display: none
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__display {
    cursor: default;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 5px
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    color: #888;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0 4px
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove:hover {
    color: #555;
    outline: none
}

.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: auto
}

.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__display {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 2px
}

.select2-container--classic[dir="rtl"] .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__choice__remove {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-selection--multiple {
    border: 1px solid #5897fb
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--above .select2-selection--multiple {
    border-top: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open.select2-container--below .select2-selection--multiple {
    border-bottom: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-search--dropdown .select2-search__field {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    outline: 0
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-dropdown {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid transparent
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-dropdown--above {
    border-bottom: none
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-dropdown--below {
    border-top: none
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-results>.select2-results__options {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-results__option--group {
    padding: 0
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-results__option--disabled {
    color: grey
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-results__option--highlighted.select2-results__option--selectable {
    background-color: #3875d7;
    color: #fff
}

.select2-container--classic .select2-results__group {
    cursor: default;
    display: block;
    padding: 6px
}

.select2-container--classic.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown {
    border-color: #5897fb
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js">
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form>
  <p>
  Test:
  </p>
        <select class="multiple-select" id="clientPickerID" name="client" style="width:60%" multiple>
                    <option> Test1 </option>
                    <option> Test2 </option>
                    <option> Test3 </option>
                    <option> Test4 </option>
                    <option> Test5 </option>
                </select>
        <br> <br>

</form>
</body>
```

Does anyone have a fix?

Thanks in advance and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative;` to the element above the form (`body` in your example)

Comment: Thanks, that solves the missplacement but clicking outside the selectbox still bugs...